# Wordpress Dashboard not loading completely

Tags: wordpress

I installed wordpress on my hosting and create a Database, Database User and done the basic platform to load the dashboard. Currently I am getting the following screen

[Admin Dashboard Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edpCi.jpg)

But when I logged with correct username and password I am getting a blank page instead of the dashboard. But when I enter my url I am getting the default site template as well as follows.

[Default template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwOWS.jpg)

Can you please help me to clarify this issue?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Can you explain more clearly so that I can help you easily?

Comment: I installed wordpress to my hosting. But after login I get a blank page instead of dashboard without displaying anything in it.I have worked on several projects in this domain and hosting and it worked pretty much fine.This is my first time facing this issue.I installed wordpress several times, repaired my tables, changed theme and plugins but still the same issue.

Comment: This means that you are facing the white screen of death issue in WordPress. https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-white-screen-of-death/ ...Tell me if this helps or I will guide you my way.